# Can't create precompiled header Z:\usr\include\stdio.h.gch: Permission denied

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors, permission-denied, cunit

I'm using a Debian9 Linux and Cpp-Dev using Wine. I'm currently trying to run some CUnit tests which were written for a program (protocol stack written in C) developed in 2006/2007. (which I need to update later)

There is:

- ...Unittest.dev file, so Dev-Cpp was used
- ...Unittest.layout file
- CUnit folder, from 2006
- suites folder, with two test suites
- xmlout folder
- main.c

The directory structure is kind a screwed. It gives me a Windows like structure. Although it adds me a Z: drive, where I can access my Linux directories writing the path in Windows style... e.g. `Z:\usr\`

I'm adding the directory `Z:\usr\include\` as include library in the compile options.

Dev-Cpp throws me this error:

`[Error] can't create precompiled header Z:\usr\include\stdio.h.gch: Permission denied`

Which is true, it should not try to write something in `\usr\include.`

Trying to stick with Dev-Cpp because it was the tool used to create this testing environment.

Work around would be, to use a Windows machine.
Want to keep the whole environment on Linux if possible.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Switch to a native IDE. Seriously, the hassle doesn't worth it.

Comment: Agree with Eugene. I've never quite understood the desire to make Windows like Linux and Linux like Windows. When in Rome do as the Romans do and most of the problems go away.